# Title, author and abstract not generate in Elsarticle class only

Tags: lyx, elsarticle

Title, author and abstract do not generate in Elsarticle class only. When I execute the following example in LyX, empty file generated dialog box pops. Everything after index terms is able to generate in PDF. Please help me out. Thanks in advance :)

```
\begin{document}

\title{This is the title}
\begin{abstract}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice example by Elsevier on how to use their template can be found [here](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need a `\maketitle` command for the title and the abstract to appear.

Comment: @engineer thanks for the template, it is helping a lot!!

Comment: @gernot \maketitle is working. Thanks but I am also able to produce title without using it.

Comment: It works by enclosing everything within \begin{frontmatter} and \end{frontmatter}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the minimal document that you need to make your title and abstract appear.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\title{This is the title}
\begin{abstract}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
  ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had this issue as well (though using TeXShop; but this detail isn't relevant). For me, the solution was to put `\maketitle` *after* the `abstract` and `keyword` environments, rather than on the line after `\begin{document}`. Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to outline what I did:

1. First create a document and apply the ELSEVIER article class to it

[image: Create an Elsevier Article]

2. Then use the Begin and End Frontmatter from LyX

[image: Begin and End Frontmatter]

Of course, you may add many more things to the Front-matter and for that, I used the elsevier class article supplied in this thread to know what to place in the Frontmatter...  Really cool and easy... Thanks...